# Twists of etale cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology

In etale cohomology, for a variety $X$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ there is an isomorphism
\begin{equation}
H^n_{et}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}},\mathbb{Q}_\ell(n)) \simeq H^n_{et}(X_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)(n)
\end{equation}
which is in fact an isomorphism between representations of the absolute Galois group $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. Could anyone give a proof to it?

Comment: Let $f:X_{\overline{k}}\rightarrow\overline{k}$ the structural map. Then there is an isomorphism $Rf_*(\mathbb{Q}(n))\simeq Rf_*(\mathbb{Q})(n)$. Then because the twist is an exact functor, it commutes with cohomology : $H^*(Rf_*(\mathbb{Q})(n))=H^*(Rf_*\mathbb{Q})(n)$.

Comment: @Roland I guess the isomorphism $Rf_*(\mathbb{Q}(n)) \simeq Rf_*(\mathbb{Q})(n)$ also follows from the fact that twist is exact! Thank you.

Comment: This is more a projection formula which holds in full generality. In some contexts (for example motivic) twists aren't exact but they still comute with direct image.